# React and ReactDOM not loading using webpack, babel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am setting up a React project using webpack and babel, but I am getting the error that **React and ReactDOM can't be resolved.**

Is the problem is with the version of Webpack or Babel?

```
PS C:\Users\abhi\Desktop\mern-app> npm run webpack

> mern-app@1.0.0 webpack C:\Users\abhi\Desktop\mern-app
> webpack

ERROR in ./app.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react' in 'C:\Users\abhi\Desktop\mern-app'
 @ ./app.js 5:13-29

ERROR in ./app.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-dom' in 'C:\Users\abhi\Desktop\mern-app'
 @ ./app.js 9:16-36
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! mern-app@1.0.0 webpack: `webpack`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the mern-app@1.0.0 webpack script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\abhi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-04-21T14_25_50_508Z-debug.log
```

the configs and files are as belows

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "mern-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "webpack": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "Abhishek Kulshrestha",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "npm": "^5.8.0",
    "react": "^16.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^4.6.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.15"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require('path');

var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports ={
    entry:'./app.js',
    output:{
        filename:'bundle.js',
        path:__dirname
    },
    resolve:{
        extensions:['.js']
    },
    module:{
        rules:[{
            test:/.jsx?$/,
            use:{
                loader:'babel-loader',
                options:{
                    presets: ['env',
                                'react']
                 }
            },
            exclude:/.node_modules/

        }]
    }

}
```

**app.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class App extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return '<h1>Hello </h1>'
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('app'));
```

**All files (package.json,webpack.config.js,app.js,index.html) are in same main folder**

Please Help

Comment: Did you setup with 'create-react-app'? (If not, I'd try that.)

Comment: @zanerock, no. I wanted to build it from scratch.

Comment: Good learning experience. I don't know about configuring webpack and such myself, but you could create another project using 'create-react-app' and then compare the configuration.

Comment: There's a typo in your webpack.config. `exclude:/.node_modules/` should be `exclude: /node_modules/` (no period). It might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code looks fine to me. I think you have missed the dependency installation step before running webpack command.

Please try and follow the below steps in order and see if it resolves the error.

1. Run `npm install` inside the directory this will make sure all the dependencies you have mentioned in package.json are downloaded to **node_modules** directory.
2. Then run `npm run webpack` to generate the bundle.js